# Converting std::string with escape sequence to ascii values

Tags: c++, string, flex-lexer

I have an std::string which I want to iterate and basically turn into a stream of int values that represent the ascii value of each character.

my problem is with escape characters. such as "\n".

```
std::string str = "hello\nhello";

for (char c : str) {
   int asciiVal = static_cast<int>(c);
   // now do something with val. but what about the escape sequence?
}
```

The problem is that this code just treat "\n" as two separate characters.

UPDATE:

this is a real problem.
yes, it does not happen in a normal c++ code but does on a .lex file that contains C/C++ excerpts.
here is the real code and the output:

CODE: .lex file

```
char *c = yytext;
c[yyleng-1] = '\0';
c++;

std::string str = c;

cout << "MY STRING: '" << str << "'" << endl;

for (char c : str) {
    int val = static_cast<int>(c);
    std::cout << to_string(val) << std::endl;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
MY STRING: '\n' 
92 
110
```

Comment: Unclear why you need that, but just escape the escape character: `'\\'`.

Comment: I need that in order to integrate with an external function that take ascii values. so for instance I need to supply the ascii value of '\n' so that this function will work properly.

Comment: Why did you tag a C++ question [tag:c]?

Comment: _"The problem is that this code just treat "\n" as two separate characters."_ No it doesn't. -1 because this question is basically a big lie :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not a lie. check update.

Comment: Yeah, you just changed it _completely_........

Comment: Thought it was a local C++ problem. happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the problem is that this code just treat "\n" as two separate characters.
>
> any help?

No it doesn't. Escape characters are store just as regular chars - so `\n` will be treated just as `a` or `b` will.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/

You can verify by printing out the `asciiVal`. In your case, the output is:

```
104  // h
101  // e
108  // l
108  // l
111  // o
10   // \n
104  // h
101  // e
108  // l
108  // l
111  // o
```

Answer (score 1):

No, `"\n"` will be treated as a single `char` (0x0a). If you want two `char`s use `"\\n"`.

Comment: well, I checked and you seem to be right. and it does work on a normal c++ code. but it seems not to work on my project (.y file for yacc/bison).
I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

In your altered question, it is apparent that your input string *does in fact contain two separate characters*.

(This was not the case in the original version of the question.)

So you will have to resolve them yourself, by scanning for a `'\\'` character, then (depending on what the next character is), replacing it with the required meta-character.

It would be much easier to change whatever setting you need to change to make your input string *actually* contain the `'\n'` character, rather than a backslash followed by an `'n'`.